# Using React-Native run in Xcode counter an error

Tags: xcode, react-native

I get new version of react-native and when I initialize a new project and run it in Xcode I have the error:(react-native 0.9 IOS run error).

Please help me!

```
 TransformError:
 /Users/lizi/Desktop/ATFProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/lib/index.js:
 [BABEL]
 /Users/lizi/Desktop/ATFProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/lib/index.js:
 Unknown option:
 /Users/lizi/Desktop/ATFProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-transform-hmr/node_modules/react-proxy/node_modules/react-deep-force-update/.babelrc.stage
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an error generated when you transpiling with [babel](https://babeljs.io/). Make sure the Node version is latest. Clear *npm cache* with `$ sudo npm cache clean` and start a new project using RN again.